# Python social auth in django to post URL to my business Facebook page using application access token

Tags: python, django, facebook, access-token, python-social-auth

I have a Django application that I want to post links to my Business page that are crawled by Facebook to produce image and summary. I have my authentication token, and this allows me to post to my page and my business page as me, but ideally what I want is to post to my business page either as the business, or the application because when I post the link to my business page as me using the following code, the URL is not scanned (My business page facebook id is magiclampmwa):

```
from fbposter.models import FacebookStatus
import facebook
import oauth2 as oauth
import urllib
import json
```

...

```
social_auths = myuser.social_auth.all()
postedmsg = ""
for social_auth in social_auths:
    access_token = social_auth.extra_data['access_token']
    theprovider = social_auth.provider
    postedmsg += "<h1>"+ theprovider +"</h1>"
    if theprovider == 'facebook':
        #try:
        for i in range(messages.count()):                  
            status = messages[i]
            #app_actk = facebook.get_app_access_token(settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY,
                    #settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET)
            graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)

            if status.link[:7] == "http://":                
                fbpost          = {}
                fbpost['name'] = "Magic Lamp"
                fbpost['link'] = status.link
                fbmsg       = status.message
                fbPost      = graph.put_wall_post(fbmsg, fbpost, 'magiclampmwa')
            else:
                fbPost      = graph.put_object('magiclampmwa', 'feed', message=status.message)
            # now like it
            graph.put_like(fbPost['id'])

            status.publish_timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
            status.save()
            postedmsg += status.message + "<BR />"
        # next i
```

Also I would like the image to be crawled as in the image below where I post to my personal page;
[image: The URL is crawled by Facebook when my App posts to my personal page as me]

but when my app posts to my business page as me using my businesses Facebook id

```
fbPost      = graph.put_wall_post(fbmsg, fbpost, 'magiclampmwa')\
```

The URL is not crawled, and the post is way down at the bottom of the page in a small box on the left hand side margin;

[image: My app posting to my business page as me]

Here are the permissions I request in my settings. The "magage_pages" authority is what I need according to the Facebook developer documentation, and that is included here:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = [
    'email',
    'user_birthday',
    'user_work_history',
    'user_education_history',
    'publish_actions',
    'manage_pages',
    'status_update',
    'read_stream', 
    'publish_stream',
    'offline_access',

]
```

And this is the authorization window where I give permission to manage my pages
[image]

I figured once I gave this authorization that python social auth would store two access tokens, one for my personal Facebook account, and one for my business page, but this is not the case. What I get in the social_auths table is only one added record for my account, and the "Extra data" field only gets populated with one access_token.

Does anyone have an idea on how to get my Business Page's access token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here:
[How to get Page Access Token by code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25470403/how-to-get-page-access-token-by-code)

- First I got my access token using python social auth through django (this is well documented) with with manage_pages and publish_actions.
- Once my application was authorised, I used it's secret and key to 
  generate Extended User Token (valid for 60 days):
  https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=[app-id]&client_secret=[app-secret]&fb_exchange_token=[short-lived-token]
- Then, I used this extended user token in: 
  https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=[ext-token]
  to give me the access token I could finally use to post to my business page.

Comment: This worked for a while, then stopped working. I found issues with Automated facebook posts not working when the post occurs through Nginx. If I set a delay and ran the post through celery instead the post worked and was scraped.